# What's the design pattern and advatages of holding a shared_ptr to the implementation within a Class?

Tags: c++

Such as:

```cpp
//Foo.cpp
class Foo{
    private:
         std::shared_ptr<FooImpl> impl_;
}

//FooImpl.cpp
class FooImpl{
    //in this class, major implementations of Foo's details are in here.
}
```

Above is the example. `FooImpl` gives the memory allocating, instances variables defining and so on. `Foo` only holds a `private` shared_ptr to an instance of the `FooImpl`.

Comment: Search for the "pimpl idiom"

Comment: @AlanBirtles Please create an answer or propose a duplicate.

Comment: @Yunnosch I couldn't be bothered writing an answer for such a well documented topic but couldn't immediately find a duplicate either, feel free to find a duplicate yourself

Comment: Btw, the `shared_ptr<>` serves to let several `Foo` objects reference the same logical objects. The copy constructor and assignment operators are likely to be implemented directly in `Foo`, and not as a call-through. If that were not the goal of the author, the `shared_ptr<>` should be replaced with a `unique_ptr<>` to avoid the overhead of the reference count that only ever reaches `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The design pattern is "The pimpl idiom" (which gets it's name by abbreviating **P**ointer to **Impl**ementation).

The design pattern consists of putting the implementation of a class (the "implementation") in a .cpp file, and leaving in the header file only the definition of an interface/entry point to that class (your "Foo" external class in your example).

Some of the advantages:

- the dependencies of the implementation class do not need to be included in the header declaring the Foo class. This can speed up compilation and avoid importing a library you want to avoid having all-over your code base.
- the polymorphic character of FooImpl is preserved. Client code only works with the interface of Foo, but you can hide multiple implementations behind it, by specializing FooImpl through inheritance, and instantiating the pointer with a derived class.
- The ABI remains stable. In case your FooImpl has an API that is templated (or one that changes very often), making any change to the API of FooImpl would trigger the rebuilding of all the code that includes Foo's header file. This is an operation that (depending on your code base) can take minutes or hours. By hiding the definition of FooImpl inside Foo.cpp, when you modify the API of FooImpl, building the modified code involves only recompiling Foo.cpp and linking everything again.

Comment: Would you like to extend your answer by the helpful mentioning of "PIMPL", as by Alan Birtles? He already indicated that he would not mind. Or in case you disagree, maybe contrast against that concept. (My level of knowledge here means I cannot make a good answer, o rmeaningfully upvote, sorry. I am happy yours exists, even if you keep it as is.)

Comment: I have extended my answer.

Comment: Oh what the ... I am pretty sure that incorporating good input, in combination with some more discussion of your own makes this answer upvotable. So forget about me not being a guru here. Have mine. ;-)